# CakePHP 3.6.14: Bootstrap table is sorting by html not text

Tags: php, html, cakephp, bootstrap-table

I am using `bootstrap table` with `cakephp`. The content of each cell is a link, so in order to display the text and not the html code I am using `data-escape="false"` in the `<table>` tag.

But now when I try to sort, sorting is not working as expected because it sorts the rows based on the html code of the link and not the text displayed.

This is my table:

```
<table class="table responsive" id="table" data-toggle="table"
    data-search="true"
    data-filter-control="true" 
    data-show-export="true"
    data-click-to-select="true"
    data-toolbar="#toolbar"
    data-escape="false">
    <thead>
        <tr>
              <th data-field="name" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true" scope="col"><?= __('Title') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php foreach ($tasks as $task):?>
           <tr>
              <td><?= $task->has('name') ? $this->Html->link($task->name, ['controller' => 'Tasks', 'action' => 'edit', $task->id]) : '' ?></td>
           </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you see http://live.datatables.net/pokafaqa/2/edit ?

Comment: @PHPnoob I need some bootstrap table functions like filter, search etc. Thats why I am using bootstrap tables

Comment: My bad, I confused these two libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your own javascript sorter with "data-sorter" attribute.

```
<th data-field="name" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true" data-sorter="linksSorter" scope="col"><?= __('Title') ?></th>
```

Then for example :

```
function linksSorter(a, b) {
    var a = $(a).text();
    var b = $(b).text();
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;

    return 0;
}
```